# HTML Slideshow Width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was working on a homepage for my band and wanted to add an slideshow element from an external source, but I discovered a problem which I was not able to fix.

The slideshow I am using has an absolute size of `600 x 300px` and I'm not able to change that. Neither can I adjust the position of the slideshow. I want it to be centered in the middle of the side and to have a width of about 75% of the site. The height should be 50% of the width. In the following I'll add the HTML-Text.

I won't add the JavaScripts as it would be too much, but you can find them [here](http://www.jssor.com/download.html). I used `jssor.slider.js`, `jssor.js` and `jquery-1.9.1.min.js`.

```js
  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                //Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-slideshow-jquery.html
                //Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/tool-slideshow-transition-viewer.html

                var _SlideshowTransitions = [
                //Fade in R
                {$Duration: 1200, x: -0.3, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7] }, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2 }
                //Fade out L
                , { $Duration: 1200, x: 0.3, $SlideOut: true, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2 }
                ];

                var options = {
                    $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
                    $AutoPlaySteps: 1,                                  //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), the default value is 1
                    $AutoPlayInterval: 4000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
                    $PauseOnHover: 1,                               //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, 4 freeze for desktop, 8 freeze for touch device, 12 freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1

                    $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                    //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
                    $SlideDuration: 500,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
                    $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
                    //$SlideWidth: 600,                                 //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
                    //$SlideHeight: 300,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
                    $SlideSpacing: 0,                           //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
                    $DisplayPieces: 1,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
                    $ParkingPosition: 0,                                //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
                    $UISearchMode: 1,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
                    $PlayOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 5 horizental reverse, 6 vertical reverse, default value is 1
                    $DragOrientation: 3,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)

                    $SlideshowOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
                        $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
                        $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,            //[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
                        $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           //[Optional] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
                        $ShowLink: true                                    //[Optional] Whether to bring slide link on top of the slider when slideshow is running, default value is false
                    },

                    $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
                        $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                       //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
                        $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                        $Lanes: 1,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange items, default value is 1
                        $SpacingX: 10,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                        $SpacingY: 10                                    //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                    },

                    $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                        $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                        $ChanceToShow: 2,                                //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                        $AutoCenter: 2                                 //[Optional] Auto center navigator in parent container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                    },

                    $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
                        $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,              //[Required] Class to create thumbnail navigator instance
                        $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                        $ActionMode: 0,                                 //[Optional] 0 None, 1 act by click, 2 act by mouse hover, 3 both, default value is 1
                        $DisableDrag: true                              //[Optional] Disable drag or not, default value is false
                    }
                };

                var jssor_sliderb = new $JssorSlider$("sliderb_container", options);
                //responsive code begin
                //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
                function ScaleSlider() {
                    var parentWidth = jssor_sliderb.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
                    if (parentWidth)
                        jssor_sliderb.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(parentWidth, 600));
                    else
                        window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
                }
                ScaleSlider();

                $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
                $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
                $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
                //responsive code end
            });
```

```css
.captionOrange, .captionBlack
            {
                color: #fff;
                font-size: 20px;
                line-height: 30px;
                text-align: center;
                border-radius: 4px;
            }
            .captionOrange
            {
                background: #EB5100;
                background-color: rgba(235, 81, 0, 0.6);
            }
            .captionBlack
            {
              font-size:16px;
                background: #000;
                background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
            }
            a.captionOrange, A.captionOrange:active, A.captionOrange:visited
            {
              color: #ffffff;
              text-decoration: none;
            }
            a.captionOrange:hover
            {
                color: #eb5100;
                text-decoration: underline;
                background-color: #eeeeee;
                background-color: rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.7);
            }
            .bricon
            {
                background: url(../img/browser-icons.png);
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="Tlogo" src="placeholder.jpg" alt="Something went badly wrong, sorry :-("
    <div id="Tmenu">
      <ul id="Navigation">
        <li><a id="aktuell" href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="UeberUns.html">&Uuml;ber Uns</a>
     <ul>
       <li><a href="DieBand.html">Die Band</a></li>
       <li><a href="Equipment.html">Equipment</a></li>
     </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="Musik.html">Musik</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="Album1.html">Musik1</a></li>
            <li><a href="Album2.html">Musik2</a></li>
            <li><a href="Album3.html">Musik3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">[Coming Soon]</a></li>
        <li><a href="Kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
        <li><a href="">[Intern]</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div></div>
    </div>

        <!-- Jssor Slider Begin -->
        <!-- You can move inline styles to css file or css block. -->
        <div id="sliderb_container" style="position: relative; width: 600px;
            height: 300px; overflow: hidden;">

            <!-- Loading Screen -->
            <div u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
                <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity:0.7; position: absolute; display: block;
                    background-color: #000; top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
                </div>
                <div style="position: absolute; display: block; background: url(../img/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
                    top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Slides Container -->
            <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px;
                overflow: hidden;">
                <div>
                    <img u=image src="placeholder.jpg" />
                    <div u="thumb">Awesome News</div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img u=image src="placeholder.jpg" />
                    <div u="thumb">More News!</div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img u=image src="placeholder.jpg" />
                    <div u="thumb">Cool Stuff Happening out there!</div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img u=image src="placeholder.jpg" />
                    <div u="thumb">Eat all the Grass that you want!!!</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- ThumbnailNavigator Skin Begin -->
            <div u="thumbnavigator" class="sliderb-T" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; height:45px; width:600px;">
                <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=40); opacity:0.4; position: absolute; display: block;
                    background-color: #000000; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                </div>
                <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin Begin -->
                <div u="slides">
                    <div u="prototype" style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 600px; HEIGHT: 45px; TOP: 0; LEFT: 0;">
                        <div u="thumbnailtemplate" style="font-family: verdana; font-weight: normal; POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 100%; HEIGHT: 100%; TOP: 0; LEFT: 0; color:#fff; line-height: 45px; font-size:20px; padding-left:10px;"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin End -->
            </div>
            <!-- ThumbnailNavigator Skin End -->
            
            <!-- Bullet Navigator Skin Begin -->
            <!-- jssor slider bullet navigator skin 01 -->
            <style>
                /*
                .jssorb01 div           (normal)
                .jssorb01 div:hover     (normal mouseover)
                .jssorb01 .av           (active)
                .jssorb01 .av:hover     (active mouseover)
                .jssorb01 .dn           (mousedown)
                */
                .jssorb01 div, .jssorb01 div:hover, .jssorb01 .av
                {
                    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
                    opacity: .7;
                    overflow:hidden;
                    cursor: pointer;
                    border: #000 1px solid;
                }
                .jssorb01 div { background-color: gray; }
                .jssorb01 div:hover, .jssorb01 .av:hover { background-color: #d3d3d3; }
                .jssorb01 .av { background-color: #fff; }
                .jssorb01 .dn, .jssorb01 .dn:hover { background-color: #555555; }
            </style>
            <!-- bullet navigator container -->
            <div u="navigator" class="jssorb01" style="position: absolute; bottom: 16px; right: 10px;">
                <!-- bullet navigator item prototype -->
                <div u="prototype" style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 12px; HEIGHT: 12px;"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- Bullet Navigator Skin End -->
            
            <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin Begin -->
            <style>
                /* jssor slider arrow navigator skin 05 css */
                /*
                .jssora05l              (normal)
                .jssora05r              (normal)
                .jssora05l:hover        (normal mouseover)
                .jssora05r:hover        (normal mouseover)
                .jssora05ldn            (mousedown)
                .jssora05rdn            (mousedown)
                */
                .jssora05l, .jssora05r, .jssora05ldn, .jssora05rdn
                {
                  position: absolute;
                  cursor: pointer;
                  display: block;
                    background: url(../img/a17.png) no-repeat;
                    overflow:hidden;
                }
                .jssora05l { background-position: -10px -40px; }
                .jssora05r { background-position: -70px -40px; }
                .jssora05l:hover { background-position: -130px -40px; }
                .jssora05r:hover { background-position: -190px -40px; }
                .jssora05ldn { background-position: -250px -40px; }
                .jssora05rdn { background-position: -310px -40px; }
            </style>
            <!-- Arrow Left -->
            <span u="arrowleft" class="jssora05l" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; top: 123px; left: 8px;">
            </span>
            <!-- Arrow Right -->
            <span u="arrowright" class="jssora05r" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; top: 123px; right: 8px">
            </span>
            <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin End -->
            <a style="display: none" href="http://www.jssor.com">Image Slider</a>
            <!-- Trigger -->
        </div>
        <!-- Jssor Slider End -->
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change the height and width of your slider from this part of your code.

```
<div id="sliderb_container" style="position: relative; width: 600px;
    height: 300px; overflow: hidden;">
```

With your current implementation that will do the trick as you have commented out the height and width on the jssor side. It will automatically pick up the height and width that you set here.

And to manage the position of the slider, add a additional container to wrap your entire code and use CSS magic. Do not change the default implementation of the codes that you got from jssor apart from the height and width.

```
<div class='wrapper' style='margin-left:15%;margin-right:15%'>
//all the contents inside the div with id = "sliderb_container" including the div 
</div>
```

This should do the trick. Look at some of their examples in the downloads, that will give you some more ideas as well.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your help :) Strangely the size-changing is not working. If I change the size from 600x300 to for example 1000x500 it looks like this: http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3875/i4937is6_png.htm (The total size of the slider doesn't change at all) But the positioning is working, thanks :)

Comment: Fixed it. Turned out, I just made a Typo... Question can be closed, thanks :)

Comment: Glad you had it fixed. Now can I has my internet cookie by accepting me answer please ;) .